# Odoo module fails when adding action to menu

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

I am facing creating menu with submenu in Odoo. I have added action action_xxx_credentials which is created in database however as soon as I add action="action_xxx_credentials" to menuitems it fails by giving error (below), Please advice how can I fix this problem

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <menuitem id="menu_xxx_root"
              name = "XXX"
              sequence="10"/>
</odoo>
```

**credentials.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="action_xxx_credentials" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name"> Credentials </field>
        <field name="type"> ir.actions.act_window </field>
        <field name="res_model">xxx.credentials</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem id="menu_xxx_settings"
              name ="Credentials"
              parent="menu_xxx_root"
              action="action_xxx_credentials"
              sequence="10"/>
</odoo>
```

**Full Error:**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 698, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 486, in _tag_menuitem
    menu = self.env['ir.ui.menu']._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 4361, in _load_records
    data['record']._load_records_write(data['values'])
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 4292, in _load_records_write
    self.write(values)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_menu.py", line 169, in write
    return super(IrUiMenu, self).write(values)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 3752, in write
    field.write(self, value)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/fields.py", line 1124, in write
    cache_value = self.convert_to_cache(value, records)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/fields.py", line 2771, in convert_to_cache
    raise ValueError("Wrong value for %s: %r" % (self, value))
ValueError: Wrong value for ir.ui.menu.action: ' ir.actions.act_window ,382'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1584, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 133, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1611, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1815, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 235, in _dispatch
    response = super()._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 154, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 697, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 46, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 33, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 461, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 448, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-80>", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 76, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 682, in button_immediate_upgrade
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 615, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "<decorator-gen-14>", line 2, in new
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/func.py", line 87, in locked
    return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 90, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 484, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 372, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 231, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 71, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 763, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 829, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 749, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 711, in _tag_root
    raise ParseError('while parsing %s:%s, somewhere inside\n%s' % (
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing /opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/payment_xxx/views/credentials.xml:12, somewhere inside
<menuitem id="menu_xxx_settings" name="XXX Credentials" parent="menu_xxx_root" action="action_xxx_credentials"/>

The above server error caused the following client error:
RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
    at makeErrorFromResponse (http://10.10.10.3:8069/web/assets/305-c88f6a8/web.assets_backend.min.js:985:163)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://10.10.10.3:8069/web/assets/305-c88f6a8/web.assets_backend.min.js:993:13)
```

Full error code above.

Comment: You're sure there is no other Error mentioned earlier in the log?

Comment: Updated full error message

Comment: oh try to delete those weird spaces in the `<field name="type"> ir.actions.act_window </field>`